# How do I configure a Vista Ultimate (64bit) account so it can access a SMB share on OSX?

Tags: macos, windows-vista, smb

I have Windows File sharing enabled on an OS X 10.4 computer. It's accessible via \rudy\myshare for all the Windows users on the network, except for one guy running Vista Ultimate 64-bit edition.

All the other users are running Vista or XP, all 32-bit. All the workgroup information is the same, all login with the same username/password.

The Vista 64 guy can see the Mac on the network, but his login is rejected every time.

Now, I imagine that Vista Ultimate is has something configured differently to the Business version and XP but I don't really know where to look. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the local security policy on that Vista box for "Local Policies\Security Options\Network Security: LAN manager authentication level" from “Send NTLMv2 response only” to “Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated”.

Answer (score 0):

No I have successfully done this with my Vista 64-bit machine.  You may want to try using the IP Address of the machine and try connecting that way.  Or maybe check out the log files on the Mac to see what the rejection error was.